# Method Perform inside ListBox class

Tags: listbox, c++builder

could someone please tell me (or give me a proper link) what is method **Perform** inside of **ListBox** class used for?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Perform()` method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform) sends a window message directly to the control's `WindowProc` without going through the calling thread's message queue.  It is similar to the Win32 API `SendMessage()` function, but without going through the API to deliver the message.